# Template casting

Tags: java, class-hierarchy

Given the following class hierarchy

```
public class BaseClass {

}

public class ExtendedClass extends BaseClass{

}
```

Is there any reason why I can't cast an instance of a generic class using the `baseClass` into that same class using the extended one?
e.g.

```
List<ExtendedClass> extendedList = (List<ExtendedClass>) new LinkedList<BaseClass>();
```

Is there any way to obtain a similar behaviour that doesn't force me to add all the elements from the first list into the second.

Comment: Every extension of BaseClass cannot be cast as ExtendedClass.

Comment: @Zefick misstyped. That was exactly the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is forbidden because otherwise you will be able to do this.

```
List<Base> base = new ArrayList<>();
List<Extended> extended = (List<Extended>)base;

base.add(new OtherExtended()); // now you have OtherExtended in List<Extended>.
```

You can force compiler to do what you want by `List<ExtendedClass> extendedList = (List<ExtendedClass>)(Object) new LinkedList<BaseClass>();`, but I suggest you not to.

**EDIT**

If you have opposite situation:

```
List<Extended> extended = new ArrayList<>();
List<Base> base = (List<Base>)base;
```

you can do

```
base.add(new OtherExtended());
```

and have same problem. `extended` again contains wrong object.

Comment: Note that you *can* do `List<Extended> extended = (List<Extended>) (List<?>) base;`, but it will produce an unchecked cast warning, and you will get a ClassCastException when retrieving instances from `extended`.

Comment: OK! I understand that the list could contain elements from other types and that is not allowed. What about a class implementing an interface? Let's say `class BaseClass implements Interface` and I want to cast a `List<BaseClass>` elements into a `List<Interface>`